# Getting user in API routes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

Inside my API routes, Auth::user() does not return anything.

I've read that this is because API's are stateless. And I should use Passport.

Could anyone explain why this is and if there is any way to get the Auth user in the API without using passport (or similar)?

Comment: the `API` routes use the `auth:api` guard, which does not use `web middleware`, which means there are no `sessions` attached to it. Passport is there to bridge the gap between a user and the API by using `token based authentication`. If you want your API to use sessions, simply give it `auth` instead of `auth:api` middleware.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information, so ideally I should use passport for api routes?

Comment: You should use whatever tool you think is best for your position, that question is really primarily opinion based.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Excellent, post it as an answer

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yes post it as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `API` routes use the `auth:api` guard, and do not use `web middleware`, which means there are no `sessions` attached to it. Passport is there to bridge the gap between a user and the API by `using token based authentication`. If you want your API to use sessions, simply give it `auth` instead of `auth:api` middleware

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) which uses token based authentication. It provides an 'jwt.auth' middleware through which you can access Auth::user() without session over an api.